# How to get name of property which our attribute is set?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm going to do this without passing any parameter to attribute! Is it possible?

```
class MyAtt : Attribute {
    string NameOfSettedProperty() {
        //How do this? (Would be MyProp for example)
    }
}

class MyCls {
    [MyAtt]
    int MyProp { get { return 10; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are metadata applied to members of a type, the type itself, method parameters, or the assembly. For you to have access to the metadata, you must have had the original member itself to user `GetCustomAttributes` etc, i.e. your instance of `Type`, `PropertyInfo`, `FieldInfo` etc.

In your case, I would actually pass the name of the property to the attribute itself:

```
public CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
  public CustomAttribute(string propertyName)
  {
    this.PropertyName = propertyName;
  }

  public string PropertyName { get; private set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
  [Custom("MyProperty")]
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i know this can be resolved by passing property-name, I'm going to do this without passing property-name. So based on your response it isn't possible.

Comment: Not possible, attributes are not passed information about the members they are attached to. What would be handy is if the `Attribute` instance was passed the `ICustomAttributeProvider` that was used to create it, but sadly this is not the case.

Comment: This comment is out of date. See below if using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 184):

Using [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) from .NET 4.5:

```
public CustomAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Saves a parameter for an attribute that I'll have to use to decorate properties across the entire project.

Comment: Was looking for this but doesn't work [with enums](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28094024/465942) unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it within the attribute class itself.  however, you *can* have a method that takes an object gets a list of that object's properties (if any) that use the attribute.    use this API to implement that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130869.aspx

Comment: OK I know there bunch of ways (one like your approach), but none of those is my case.