# CallerMemberName and enums

Tags: c#, enums

From this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15738041/1250301

To this question:

[How to get name of property which our attribute is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606973/how-to-get-name-of-property-which-our-attribute-is-set)

You can use `CallerMemberName` to figure out which property an attribute is attached too. Which is pretty cool. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with enums. For example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/B69FCx

```
public static void Main()
{   
    var mi = typeof(MyEnum).GetMember("Value1");
    var attr = mi[0].GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>();

    mi = typeof(Bar).GetMember("SomeProp");
    attr = mi[0].GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>();
}

public class Bar
{
    [Foo]
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}

public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public FooAttribute([CallerMemberName]string propName = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Propname = " + propName);
    }
}

enum MyEnum  
{
    [Foo]
    Value1,
    [Foo]
    Value2
};
```

`propName` when you access it for a `MyEnum` is null, but for the class `Bar` it works as expected (i.e. it's `SomeProp`). Is there a way to make this or something similar work for an enum? Or am I stuck with adding a property to `FooAttribute` and setting it when I add the property to the enum:

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyEnum AttachedTo { get; set; }
}

enum MyEnum  
{
    [Foo(AttachedTo = MyEnum.Value1)]
    Value1,
    [Foo(AttachedTo = MyEnum.Value2)]
    Value2
};
```

Which is tedious and has potential to be error prone.

Comment: Not sure why you got DV'd. Seems like a reasonable and interesting problem to me!

Answer (score 0):

`CallerMemberName` is not available for Assembly level or `const` members. Since an Enum value is essentially a const, you can't get that information. You will see the same behavior if you apply `[Foo]` to a `public const` member on `class Bar`.

As I was putting together a test, my inner voice kept screaming that I was doing something wrong. Having attributes on const's seems to be in opposition to the nature of decorators in general. I feel like you're getting into uncharted, 'Here there be monsters,' territory. You may want to rethink your design and consider a different path.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong we attaching meta data to enum values. There are lots of examples out there including [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Here are some more: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapenumattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: These aren't just examples. These are classes in the .NET library expressly for the purpose of attaching metadata to members of an enum. It's a tool like any other (as are singletons) that can be used or misused.